# Initializing enum-indexed array?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, enums, g++

gcc has a very nice extension in C that allows you to keep data in arrays using enum as keys:

```
 enum keys
 {
      key_alpha = 0,
      key_beta = 1,
      key_gamma = 2
 };

 ValType values = 
 {
      [ key_alpha ] = { 0x03b1,"alpha" },
      [ key_gamma ] = { 0x03b3,"gamma" },
      [ key_beta ]  = { 0x03b2,"beta" }
 };
```

This is nice because if the list has to change, adding or removing a line doesn't destroy the assignment, it is obvious which key corresponds to which value, and results in simple code no different from plain standard array initialization.

Unfortunately, this extension is not available in g++.

What would be the preferred lightweight way of doing the same thing in C++? Preferably something not based on <map> and the likes that use string keys, hidden indices, heavy templates or other CPU- and memory-heavy stuff?

Comment: Is C++11 acceptable in solutions?

Comment: It is called `designated initializers` which is available in C99, and compilers may provide this as extension.

Comment: (BTW your example code is missing semicolons)

Comment: @Nawaz: gcc has this on by default, and the GCC extensions page lists it specifically as a feature not present in g++.

Comment: Can we rephrase the question to: "Is it possible in C++ to initialize an array by specifying the elements in arbitrary order?"

Comment: @Kerrek: Not necesserily. Older version of GCC had a simplified version of this, that required the order and sequence to be maintained - it didn't modify behavior at compile time, the keys only served to check correctness, print error if declared keys didn't match the order. This would be satisfactory. e.g. current arrangement would generate error, and to compile gamma would have to go after beta.

Comment: @SF: Oh OK. I just checked and discovered that you *can* fill an array in random order and "with holes" in C99, and was quite thrilled. I think no such thing exists in C++.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

#define KEYS_DEF \
    KEY_DEF( alpha, 0x03b1, "alpha" ),  \
    KEY_DEF( beta,  0x03b2, "beta" ),   \
    KEY_DEF( gamma, 0x03b3, "gamma" )

#define KEY_DEF( identifier, id, name )  identifier
enum keys { KEYS_DEF };

#undef KEY_DEF
#define KEY_DEF( identifier, id, name )  { id, name }
struct ValType { int id; char const* name; };
ValType const values[] = { KEYS_DEF };

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    for( int i = alpha;  i <= gamma;  ++i )
    {
        cout << values[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this extension exists precisely because there is no simple, portable way of achieving this behaviour. You can emulate it using something like:

```
enum keys
{
  key_alpha = 0,
  key_beta = 1,
  key_gamma = 2
};

struct ValType {
  int v;
  const char *name;
};

template <int key>
struct param;

#define SETPARAM(key,value1,value2) \
template <> \
struct param< (key) > { \
  static constexpr ValType t {(value1),(value2)}; \
}

SETPARAM(key_alpha, 0x03b1,"alpha");
SETPARAM(key_gamma, 0x03b3,"gamma");
SETPARAM(key_beta, 0x03b2,"beta");
```

which is portable and meets your requirements without being particularly "heavy templates".

If you're not using C++11 you can still do this, the macro that specialises the `param` template will become slightly longer though.

---

Modification to make use like `int i = someinput(); cout << param<i>::t.name;` legal:

```
#include <cassert>

enum keys
{
  key_alpha = 0,
  key_beta = 1,
  key_gamma = 2
};

struct ValType {
  int v;
  const char *name;
};

template <int key>
struct param {
  enum { defined = false };
  static constexpr ValType t {0, 0};
};

template <int key>
constexpr ValType param<key>::t;

static const int MAXPARAM=255;

#define SETPARAM(key,value1,value2) \
template <> \
struct param< (key) > { \
  static_assert(key <= MAXPARAM, "key too big"); \
  enum { defined = true }; \
  static constexpr ValType t {(value1),(value2)}; \
}; \
constexpr ValType param<(key)>::t

template <int C=0>
struct get_helper {
  static const ValType& get(int i) {
    return i==0 ? (check(), param<C>::t) : get_helper<C+1>::get(i-1);
  }
private:
  static void check() {
    assert(param<C>::defined);
  }
};

template <>
struct get_helper<MAXPARAM> {
  static const ValType& get(int) {
    assert(false);
  }
};

const ValType& GETPARAM(int key) {
  return get_helper<>::get(key);
}
```

The trick is to instantiate `get_helper` and recurse through the calls with a flag that can be used to assert the validity of the index. You can increase `MAXPARAM` if needed, but it'll make compiling slower.

Example usage is pretty simple still:

```
#include "enumidx.hh"
#include <iostream>

SETPARAM(key_alpha, 0x03b1,"alpha");
SETPARAM(key_gamma, 0x03b3,"gamma");
SETPARAM(key_beta, 0x03b2,"beta");

int main() {
  int key = key_beta;
  const ValType& v = GETPARAM(key);
  std::cout << v.name << std::endl;
}
```

To have more than one of these in any given program you could use anonymous namespaces and/or make the name of the base `struct` (`param` in this example) a macro argument and add another macro `STARTPARAM`(?) to define the unspecialised template of that name.

Comment: This doesn't allow dynamic lookup, so I don't think it's a valid replacement.

Comment: @BenVoigt - you may be right there, I hadn't thought of that. You mean for example `int i = someinput(); cout << param<i>::t.name;` being illegal?

Comment: unfortunately that means it will be no good for me. It will be often used nested deep in functions with the key passed as argument.

Comment: @SF - I can fix this, but it moves it a lot further into the realm of "heavy templates". I don't think you'll get an answer that isn't basically just `std::map` or "heavy templates"

Comment: @SF - answer updated. I can modify it to make it more generic too, but then things start to get even more complicated!

Comment: I really hoped for something easier... I'm really pondering now `ValType values[MAX_VALS]; values[key_alpha]=...; values[key_beta]=...;`

Comment: @SF - I think this gcc extension exists precisely because there is no better+easier way of achieving the same functionality. I could be wrong though and I'm keen to see if anyone has any better answers.

Comment: Oh, I agree, but then why is it not present in C++?

Comment: @SF - I suspect it's seen as low importance in C++ given the ubiquity of containers like `std::map`.

Answer (score 2):

A cheap, sneaky, cheaty solution: define the "values" variable in a separate .c file next to all the .cpp files, define the enum and "extern values" in a .h file.

Comment: A nice example is available in Android init files parser. Values in [header](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/system/core/init/keywords.h) and variable in c [file](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/system/core/init/init_parser.c#58).